# Systems in sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Which of these quantity systems corresponds to sigma algebra?

Given is the set $\Omega =\left \{ 3,4,5 \right \}$
How do I determine which of the given quantity systems corresponds to an event algebra?

$ \left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{ 5\right \},\left \{ 3,4\right \},\left \{ 3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{ 3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

$\left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \}\right \}$

$ \left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{ 3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

$\left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{ 5\right \},\left \{ 3,4\right \},\left \{ 3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{ 3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

I think that $\left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{ 5\right \},\left \{ 3,4\right \},\left \{ 3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{ 3,4,5\right \}\right \}$ corresponds to an event algebra.

Is that only correct answer or?

I believe it’s possible, in general, to have other sigma algebras though it has to:

Have the empty set

Have compliments

Have intersections

Have unions

But still I'm not sure in my answer.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this very recently?

Answer (score 2):

My professor gave us this definition of $\sigma$-algebra:
$\Sigma\subset 2^X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if:

1. $E \in \Sigma \Rightarrow E^C \in \Sigma$
2. $\{E_j\}$ is a numerable family of elements of $\Sigma \Rightarrow \cup_j E_j \in \Sigma$

Using this definition, also $ \left \{\left \{ \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{ 3,4,5\right \}\right \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, together with the one you said.

Then, if $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, you have these two results:

1. $\emptyset, X \in \Sigma$
2. $\{E_j\}$ is a numerable family of elements of $\Sigma \Rightarrow \cap_j E_j \in \Sigma$

P.S.: Your first and last sets are the same.